# Prevent \listofalgorithms from producing blank page

Tags: table-of-contents, algorithms, blank-page

I'm writing my thesis with latex, and there's a chapter in which are described some algorithms using the algorithmicx package. What I want to do is to place an index of algorithms at the very beginning of the chapter, so I've tried

```
\chapter{Algoritmi per la ricerca}
\label{ch:algoritmi}

\listofalgorithms

Text of the chapter....
```

The problem is that the command \listofalgorithms produces a blank page between the chapter title and the list of algorithms.

Is there a way to avoid this?

I'm using document class scrbook.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following to suppress the page break:

```
{\let\clearpage\relax\listofalgorithms}
```

Comment: It works! Thank you very much! :-D